# Basic User Poll of Upcoming Game Interests - Iteration the First

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion, sponsorship

Yes, this is in relation to [our Community Promotion Grant](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2010/community-promotion-sponsorship-new-game-releases-for-community-members). If you have not read about it, please consult that link before you return here. ♪

> ### Poll is closed now.
>
> The game has been selected: **Witcher 2: Assassins of Kings**. I think that's the right subtitle, at least. I find it better to go by memory than to look stuff up, hooha! If I'm wrong, well, the game is whatever **Witcher 2** would be if it had the proper subtitle!
>
> If you are among the selected for this promotional opportunity, you should be receiving an email for this. I look forward to seeing how everything turns out. ♪

---

If you're remotely interested in the opportunity to participate in this endeavor, then I'd like you to post a response to this question with the following information.

1. **Your available platforms for upcoming games**. I appreciate everyone who still has and can play their SNES, but I'm looking specifically for the modern generation. If you specify PC, also include the OS.
2. **Your interests in new and upcoming games**. List whatever *upcoming* games you would be interested in and intend to contribute questions towards. I'm not much to build a list of options because all of my news about the mainstream games comes from you, the Community. As such, as you think of your own interests, also consider browsing what others have specified (and revisit this when it gets updated by others).

   Please keep in mind that depending on how quickly we can gather this data, it may impact the viability of doing immediately upcoming releases (namely, *Portal 2*, which most people have already pre-ordered and have started pre-loading). As such, it would be wise to have options both in the immediate future and sometime afterwards, so that you do not get hosed by not matching any of the later options.
3. **Your availability to show up on chat**. It's flat out easier to coordinate these things on chat, and so we will probably be attempting some meetings in the chat room when we get a lot of candidates.

The results from this poll will be used to aid in the selection of both the game, and the users who will be receiving the game. In this first run, we will experiment a bit with the selection process in order to try and determine what can work best going forwards.

Do keep in mind that if you elect to receive any game that is *not* digitally distributed, we will need your mailing address, so if the following applies: make sure your parents are comfortable with that! ♪

I look forward to seeing what interests the community has. ♪

---

[This Google Document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YN2LXwFo5IZzzsr1GUpgJJm-QUZvx-H1j5-tAVRrCFM/edit?hl=en&authkey=CO6V5_cI) can be accessed and edited to accumulate a list of information on upcoming games as well. Please feel free to populate it with any new additions you can think of, even if you might not be interested in a particular one. Also feel free to correct me on any horrendous inaccuracies on the entry I've added.

Comment: There seems to be a depressing large amount of unavailability for the upcoming weeks... how curious.

Comment: Should we mention preferred platforms for upcoming releases that are multi-platform games? For instance, some prefer FPS's on console, some on PC, some prefer certain consoles over others for multiplayer options, etc.

Comment: @Fallen When the game is selected and we start to round up the users who will receive the games (and their mailing addresses), we will double check with all selections as to which platform they would prefer to receive the game on. However, please feel free to add that information on your own if you'd like. Oak was suggesting that I collapse the "platforms" and "interests" bits, too.

Comment: For those that have no clue about upcoming games, go to [Metacritic](http://www.metacritic.com) > Games > Pick Your Platform > New Releases (In the top left).

Comment: Any word on how much "(y) rep" is?

Comment: @John No, no idea yet. However, I'm more inclined to trust more with contribution history and age moreso than strict reputation.

Comment: So how do I stack up on your scale?

Comment: @John You're not *terribly* active yet, but I don't want to make judgment quite yet. Based on the results of the current poll, I'm intending to re-evaluate the strategy to account for the breadth of options, the wide timespan, and most importantly the lack of intersections. Stay tuned. ♪

Comment: I don't think I made the cut, but just in case, this is not a game I would be interested in.  FYI.

Comment: @John There's always next time. ♪

Answer (score 0):

1. **Platforms**:

   - Xbox 360
   - PC(Windows/Ubuntu)
   - PS3
   - Wii
   - Nintendo DS
2. **Game Interests**:

   - Mortal Kombat (4/19)
   - Portal (4/19, already pre-ordered)
   - Brink (5/10)
   - Gears of War 3 (9/20)
   - Batman: Arkham City (10/18)
   - Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim (11/11)
   - Diablo 3 (TBD)
3. **Availability**:

   - Pretty much anytime, I'm a college graduate student so my hours are very flexible. I'm in UTC - 6:00 and generally don't go to sleep before midnight. However, April is a terrible month for me to put a lot of time into any game as I'm currently dealing with finals.

Answer (score 0):

1) Platforms

- PC, Mac and Windows, and a fairly poorly specced machine at that, though looking to change the last part :(
- Nintendo DS
- iPhone!

2) Game Interests

- The Witcher 2 (5/17)
- Deus Ex: Human Revolution (8/23)
- The Elder Scrolls: Skyrim (11/11)
- Star Wars: The Old Republic (MMO, Who freaking knows...)
- Dungeon Siege 3
- Alice: Madness Returns

3) Availability

- I'm around basically all the time :P, based in EST. I do tend to be paying attention more in the evenings.
- It should be noted that I *will* however be gone for about 2 weeks starting this saturday. Looooooooooooooong overdue vacations.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Platforms**

   - Windows 7
   - Linux Mint 10
   - Xbox 360
   - Nintendo DS
   - PS3
2. **Game Interests:**

   - Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim (11/11)
   - Star Wars: The Old Republic (??/??)
   - Mass Effect 3
3. **General Interests:**

   - Puzzles
   - RPGs
   - Strategy

     - Turn- based
     - Real time
   - Indie
   - Music/Rhythm
   - MMO
   - Basically any genre except sports
4. **Availability:**

   - EST (UTC -5)
   - I'm on sporadically, but I can arrange to be on at specific times.
   - My internet access will be unstable or broken until ~ 4/20

Answer (score 0):

1. **Platforms:**

   - PC (Windows 7, but I can install Ubuntu 10.04 if needed)
   - PS3
   - Wii
   - DS
2. **Intrests:**

   - The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim (11/11)
   - Final Fantasy XIII-2 (Winter 2011/2012)
   - The Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword (second half of 2011)
   - Batman: Arkham City (10/18) [preferably on PS3]
   - Guild Wars 2
   - Uncharted 3: Drake's Deception (11/1)
   - Spider-Man: Edge of Time (Fall)
   - InFamous 2 (6/7)
   - Kirby (2011)
   - Pretty much any other RPG, RTS, puzzle game, or PC FPS
3. **Availability:**

   - CST (UTC-06:00)
   - I can't access chat currently, since I'm on 28Kbps dial-up, but in a week or two I'll be getting internet 150-700x as fast so I should be on there all the time then.

Answer (score 0):

1. Platforms

   - PC (Windows)
   - Xbox 360
   - Wii
   - Nintendo DS
2. Game Interests

   - Portal 2 (PC only)
   - Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim (PC only)
   - Crysis 2 (PC only)
   - The Witcher 2
   - Any interesting RPG or FPS (although I'll only play FPS games on PC; I can't stand joysticks for aiming).
3. Availability

   - EST.  I don't hang out in chat terribly often but I'm always on the main site during the day.  Ping me or something and I'll see it and come to chat.  Also, due to my full-time job, I'm not up at all hours of the night either.  10-11PM is about my limit.

Answer (score 0):

1) Platforms

- PC (Windows 7)
- PS3

2) Game Interests

- Portal 2 (No pre-order yet)
- L.A. Noire (5/17)
- The Elder Scrolls: Skyrim (11/11)
- In general: RPGs, turn-based strategy, puzzle games

3) Availability

Central Daylight Time (UTC - 06:00) , typically available around noon or between 8-10 PM

Comment: CDT is where? I should start requesting users to put down the UTC offset... crepes, there's apparently 3 different ESTs, too!

Answer (score 0):

#### Platforms

- iOS (iPhone 4, iPad)
- PlayStation 3
- PlayStation Portable
- Mac OS X
- Windows

#### Interests

Generally interested in classical, progression-based RPGs. This includes stuff like Final Fantasy, but not action RPGs like Zelda or RPG-lite games like Fallout.

PlayStation 3:

- Any [Dragon Age II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Age_II) DLC (on-going 2011/2012)
- [Dungeon Siege III](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeon_Siege_III) (June 21st, 2011)
- [White Knight Chronicles II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Knight_Chronicles_II) (Summer 2011)
- [The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_V:_Skyrim) (November 11th, 2011)
- [Final Fantasy XIII-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy_XIII-2) (TBA: Late 2011/Early 2012)
- [Final Fantasy Versus XIII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy_Versus_XIII) (TBA)

PlayStation Portable:

- [Final Fantasy IV Complete Collection](http://na.square-enix.com/ff4complete/) (April 19th, 2011)
- [Final Fantasy Type-0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy_Type-0) (TBA: Q3/4 2011)

#### Availability

I generally don't hang out in the Gaming.SE chat rooms, but if you have a set time, I can be there.

- Pacific Time (currently UTC-7)
- Prefer afternoons to late evening (3pm to 12am)

Comment: You still owe me a post about those awesome Minecraft video's @Mark ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Platforms**

- PC (Windows, Mac OSX) - Steam
- iOS (iPhone 4)
- DS
- OnLive (sort of a platform...)

**Interests**

PC RPGs and MMORPGs are what I invest the most time in. I also play the occasional FPS and indie puzzle/platformer games.

- <strike>Portal 2 (have not preordered)</strike>
- Star Wars: The Old Republic
- Guild Wars 2
- Diablo 3
- Dungeon Siege 3
- Deus Ex: Human Revolution
- L.A. Noire
- Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim
- The Witcher 2: Assassins of Kings
- Alice: Madness Returns

**Availability**

I'm often in chat. Set a time and I'll be there.

- Central time (UTC -6)

Comment: I guess what I can draw from this is that our more active populace *is* in the EST/CST area, they're just not nearly as vocal about it as those CET fellows.

Comment: @Grace - We Midwesterners don't like to make a ruckus :)

Answer (score 0):

**Platforms**

- PC (Windows, E8400+GTX560)

**Interests**

Mostly RPGs

- Portal 2 (already preordered)
- The Witcher 2: Assassins of Kings
- Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim
- Mass Effect 3

**Availability**

I'm at UTC+2 (Germany)

- Limited availability during the day, usually in chat in the evening

Answer (score 0):

**Platforms:**

- Xbox 360 with Kinect (no Xbox Live)
- PC - Windows 7
- PS3 - no Move
- iPad

**Game Interests:**

- Rock Band 3 with a Squier Stratocaster controller
- Any (sportive) Kinect game
- Preferably games you can pick up or drop easily
- Preferably games with a short campaign, so I'm done in one weekend
- Total War: Shogun 2
- Might & Magic VI
- Mortal Kombat
- Virtua Tennis
- L.A. Noire
- World of Warcraft - I'm tempted to give the expansion another shot in a casual way.
- Random iPad games, I wouldn't mind reviewing any iPad games, but I've resisted the urge of impulse buying. If it's sponsored I wouldn't mind trying out other games.

**Availability:**

European time zone, I'm a freelancer, so I'm very flexible and am online nearly every waking minute. I avoid hanging out on the Bridge, because it seriously gimps my productivity, but @Grace knows how to ping me.

Answer (score 0):

**Platforms**:

- Windows 7 PC (Very high-end, currently; e.g. Starcraft 2 graphics default to "Ultra")
- Wii
- DS
- <strike>3DS</strike> (Do not have a 3DS, but may acquire one in near future)

**Game Interests:**

- Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim
- Might & Magic VI
- Legend of Zelda Skyward Sword
- Portal Two
- Mass Effect 3
- Diablo III
- Deus Ex: Human Revolution
- Darkspore
- Brink
- Indy Games

I have a special fondness for puzzle games, though the only genre I really stray away from is "Sports".

**Availability**:

Immediately.

Eastern Time Zone, I'm a college student, so I'm very flexible and am online nearly every waking minute. Given that the semester is about to end, I should have a host of free time as well. And East Coast! I party it up in the same timezone as Grace Note! Being in chat shouldn't be a problem either, as I tend to check gaming.stackexchange religiously (275 consecutive days and counting!)

Answer (score 0):

**Platform**:

- PC

**Game Interests:**

- Portal 2

  - Not pre-ordered yet.
  - Planning on finishing at soon as possible, trying to speed run it. I'm also up for Multiplayer...
- MMORPG (WoW) / RTS (SC II) / Shooters (QL / CS:S)

**Availability:**

- UTC + 1, very active.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Platforms**

   - PC - Windows 7
   - Xbox 360 (no Kinect)
   - Playstation 3 (no Move)
   - Nintendo DS Lite
   - Sony PSP-2000
2. **Game Interests**

   1. Specific games:

      - Portal 2 (4/19, preordered, PC/Steam)
      - InFamous 2
      - Darkspore
      - Batman: Arkham City (10/18, 360)
      - Torchlight 2 (PC)
      - Dragon Age II DLC (PC, non-Steam)
      - Alice: Madness Returns (PC)
      - ICO/Shadow of the Colossus Collection (Q4 2011)
      - Saints Row: The Third (360, Q4 2011)
      - Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword (2011)
      - Neverwinter (MMO, 2011)
      - Star Wars: The Old Republic (MMO, 2011)
      - Mass Effect 3 (Holiday 2011, PC)
      - Prototype 2 (2012)
      - Diablo III (no confirmed release date)
      - Guild Wars 2 (MMO, no confirmed release date)
      - The Secret World (MMO, no confirmed release date)
      - Anything to do with current releases of Guild Wars and City of Heroes
   2. General Interests

      - Most non-sports games (not FIFA/Madden/PES/UFC/etc.) though I do like arcade racers (like Burnout) but not sim racers (like Forza/Gran Turismo)
      - Indie games - I love supporting the indie game industry
      - Music/Rhythm games (Rock Band, Audiosurf, Beat Hazard, etc.)
      - RPGs, FPS/RTS (on PC, not on console), TBS, 4X games, action/adventure, platformers, weird quirky games that I have difficulty qualifying in words... really, it's just easier to say what I *don't* play, which is the aforementioned sports stuff.
3. **Availability**

   - I live in the Netherlands in Central European (at the moment, Summer) Time, so GMT+2 currently. I'm pretty much always connected to chat, but I've been less active of late as I've found it kind of kills my productivity (including gaming time) to be actively chatting all day. I'm always available to be pinged though, as the window is always open if I am home.

Answer (score 0):

#### Platforms

- PC (Mac OS X)
- Wii
- Nintendo DS (though I doubt any games chosen would be for the DS)
- iOS (same as above)

#### Game Interests (unfortunately genre based and not specific upcoming games)

- Indie Games
- Platformers
- Puzzle Games

#### Availability

- Time Zone: PST
- Generally in the evening / nighttime

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this by saying, you don't have to send me any games.  I will match (from my own funds) whatever game goes out to everyone else.

```
Platforms = {
    Computers : ['Windows 7', 'Ubuntu 10.10'],
    Consoles : ['Xbox 360', 'Nintendo Wii'],
    Handhelds : ['Nintendo DS']
    Other : ['iPad', 'Droid X (Android)']
}

Interests = {
    CurrentPreorders : ['Portal 2', 'Mortal Kombat'],
    Considering : ['LEGO Pirates of the Caribbean: The Video Game', 
                                  'Duke Nukem Forever',
                                  'Green Lantern: Rise of the Manhunters',
                                  'UFC Personal Trainer',
                                  'Alice: Madness Returns',
                                  'Deus Ex: Human Revolution',
                                  'Gears of War 3',
                                  'Batman: Arkham City',
                                  'Darkspore',
                                  'Dungeon Siege III',
                                  'Star Wars: The Old Republic',
                                  'Torchlight 2',
                                  'Total War: Shogun 2',
                                  'Diablo III',
                                  'Legend of Zelda Skyward Sword']
}

Availability = {
    TimeZone : 'PST',
    Crontabs : ["* 6,7,8,9,10 * * 0,1,2,5",
                "* 10,11 * * 3,4"]
}
```

In json for you convenience

Comment: You have a very strange definition of "convenience". Good thing I *can* read JSON by eye, though.

Comment: If *I* were going to have to enter in data by 10+ people, I would write a parser rather than do it by hand.  Parsers for JSON usually are trivial to write... seeing as it's already JSON.

Comment: I'm too lazy to write a parser at the moment, so I'm just using pen and paper.

Comment: @Grace, I find that statement peculiar, as I'm too lazy *not* to write a parser

Comment: Well, consider that I'm the kind of person who is usually too lazy to wait for an elevator and will instead use the stairs. I don't deny that it makes for the occasionally inefficient approach.

Comment: I actually got a beta invite to Darkspore, but I was never online to play it when the window opened. :(

Comment: @Arkive I was...

Answer (score 0):

### Platforms

- PC Windows
- Mac OS X
- XBox 360 (w/ Kinect)
- PS3
- iPhone
- AndroidOS

### Interests

#### By Game

- Portal 2 (already pre-ordered)
- Duke Nukem Forever
- Serious Sam 3
- Star Wars: The Old Republic
- Darkspore
- Diablo 3
- Starcraft 2 Expansions
- Dungeon Siege III

#### By Genre

- Real-time strategy games
- RPGs
- MMORPGs
- First-person shooters
- Tower defense games
- 4x games
- Puzzle games

### Availability

- Weekdays: 8pm-11pm PST. If the conversation won't be too long, during the day.
- Weekends: I can usually be available at any time.

Answer (score 0):

1) Platforms

- PC (Windows Vista, sigh) with Steam
- Xbox 360 with Xbox Live, no Kinect
- PS3, no Move
- Wii

I no longer have my SNES, but I do have an Atari Lynx. Two, actually. :)

2a) Interests, specific

- Diablo III
- Elder Scrolls: Skyrim
- Madden 12
- Mass Effect 3
- Saints Row: The Third
- Torchlight II

2b) Interests, general

- RPGs
- Sandbox games
- Sports games
- Puzzle games
- Music games

3) Chat availability

I'm EDT (UTC -4) during the summer and EST (UTC -5) during the winter. (It's been more confusing; I live in Indiana, so yes, we had our own "time zone" ... it's much easier to explain what time it is now.)

Generally available evenings and weekends; unlikely to be available during the day.

Comment: No longer? Hah, that makes me curious about what happened. Mine... it was effectively eradicated by a bolt of lightning. It still has physical form, but its soul (and with it, the ability to display graphics on a TV) have departed this world.

Comment: @Grace, I gave it and my first Sega Genesis away to friends with kids who'd appreciate them more ... obviously that was some time ago! I think my NES is the oldest console in my collection that was originally mine: my 5200, Genesis, Intellivision, and both Lynxes were all acquired in fits of nostalgia. I would guess there will not be much of a market for questions about those!

Answer (score 0):

#### Platforms

- PC (Windows 7, Steam)
- Wii
- DS Lite
- Android

#### Interests

Here's all the major upcoming titles currently on my radar:

First, those on PC:

- *Portal 2* (already pre-ordered and pre-loaded)
- Batman: Arkham City
- Brink
- Deus Ex: Human Revolution
- DiRT 3
- Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim
- Mass Effect 3

And one non-PC:

- [Wii] Legend of Zelda Skyward Sword

#### Availability

Currently UTC+1 (UK w/ daylight savings).

Availability (you'll find me in various SU rooms whenever I'm on):

- Weekdays:

  - ~08:30 to ~14:00 most days (note: this is while at work, so I *can* chat but not much else).
  - ~20:00 to ~23:00 most days.

* Weekends:
 * ~20:00 to ~23:00 most days.

Answer (score 0):

**Platforms**

- PC (Windows 7, DX10 compatible GPU, Q9550 Intel CPU)
- PS3
- Xbox 360
- Wii
- PSP
- Nintendo DS

**Game Interests**

- RPGs (TES: Skyrim, Torchlight II, Diablo III, SW:TOR)
- Action/Platformers (Batman:AC, Infamous 2)

  These are the genres I'd say I'm most interested in, but I can and do play pretty much whatever. I'm just limiting what I put down here to help keep things nice and concise.

**Availability**

- Timezone is UTC - 8/9 depending on DST
- Available from 6PM PST to 2AM on weekdays, and pretty much anytime on weekends.

Answer (score 0):

Can I put games down not on the list? I have some far out ideas.

**Platforms**

- Mac(BookPro) (Snow Leopard)
- PS3
- Xbox 360
- Wii
- PSP
- Nintendo DS

**Game Interests**

- Shooters (DOOM, Serious Sam)
- Platformers (Donkey Kong Country, Crash Bandicoot-style)
- Music/Rhythm (Shake that thang)
- Open World Action (with a purpose) (Just Cause, Crackdown)
- Strategery (StarCraft)

And for the games themselves;

- Duke Nukem Forever
- StarCraft 2: Hive Mind
- Serious Sam 3
- Rock Band 4

**Availability**

- Timezone is America/Denver, Spring/Summer = -0600UTC, Winter = -0700UTC
- Available outside of standard US business hours, and weekends pretty much completely.

Comment: You can put down games that are not on the list, as long as they are upcoming games, yes. That said, do keep in mind that the likelihood of getting the game through this program is drastically lower if you're the only one seeking it.

Comment: I don't think that's the case with anything currently on the list :). But I appreciate the note.

Answer (score 0):

1. Platforms:

   - NDS (2D for now)
   - Xbox 360
   - Wii
   - iPhone
   - PS2
2. Game Interests:

   - RPG - mostly old school / jRPGs
   - Puzzle
   - Tower Defense (especially with zombies)
3. Availability

   - I can hop in chat between 9-5 Pacific Daylight time, and intermittent evenings (9am for me is 5pm for London).  I generally don't hang out, but pop in to see if something interesting is happening.
   - I work full time, so most of my gaming is on the bus, and some evenings.

Answer (score 0):

## Platforms

- PC (mid-range)
- Android
- DS

## Interests

Bits and pieces of everything, but simulation games are top of the list. Currently no specific upcoming games catch my fancy.

## Availability:

After 7 GMT.

* My time very limited until Mid-June however.

Answer (score 0):

**Platforms**

- Xbox 360 (Xbox LIVE Gold, no Kinect)
- PC (Win7+Steam)
- Wii
- DS

**Games**

- L.A. Noire
- Asura's Wrath
- Brink
- The Last Guardian
- Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword
- Megaman Legends 3
- Duke Nukem Forever
- Final Fantasy XIII-2
- Final Fantasy Versus XIII
- Red Faction: Armageddon

**Availability**

Anytime within hours of reasonable consciousness for UTC -4:00. Most of my free time is spent gaming anyway, so it may as well be for a cause. I like essentially every genre except sports games, but I could make the odd exception. Also, I have no qualms against picking up a new console.

Answer (score -1):

- Platforms

  - Linux
  - Wine (okay, not a platform, also not a joy to use...)
  - Windows
- Interests: this is a tricky one, because my GPU is hardly top notch, so I'd have to try the demos of A+++ titles (such as, what do I know, Doom 4?) before I'd have somebody invest the money for me to play it. I'm not too much into prereleases so I'll just mention the kind of games I try:

  - Indie stuff.
  - FPS stuff.
  - Puzzle games (sometimes).
  - ...I know them when I see them :(
- Availability: too much for my own good.